# Programmatically exposing call statistics with JMX

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jmx

What I would like to do is the following:
Exposing call statistics (basically call count and avg. call time) through JMX.
What the problem is that I would like to do this with AspectJ support (to automatically calculate it for my implementation classes).

What I created is the JmxBean:

```
public class JmxStatistics implements Serializable {

private final String name;
private long errorCount;
private long errorCallTime;
private long successCount;
private long successCallTime;

public JmxStatistics(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public synchronized long getCallCount() {
    return errorCount + successCount;
}

public synchronized long getAvgCallTimeInMillisecs() {
    return (errorCallTime + successCallTime) / getCallCount();
}

public synchronized long getAvgSuccessfulCallTimeInMillisecs() {
    return (errorCallTime + successCallTime) / successCount;
}

public synchronized long getAvgFailedCallTimeInMillisecs() {
    return (errorCallTime + successCallTime) / errorCount;
}

public synchronized void increaseErrorCallTime(long sumCallTime) {
    this.errorCallTime += sumCallTime;
}

public synchronized void increaseSuccessCallTime(long sumCallTime) {
    this.successCallTime += sumCallTime;
}

public synchronized long getErrorCount() {
    return errorCount;
}

public synchronized void incrementErrorCount() {
    this.errorCount++;
}

public synchronized long getSuccessCount() {
    return successCount;
}

public synchronized void incrementSuccessCount() {
    this.successCount++;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + "{" + "callCount=" + getCallCount()
            + " (s: " + successCount + ",e:" + errorCount + "); "
            + "avgCallTime=" + getAvgCallTimeInMillisecs() + "ms "
            + "(" + getAvgSuccessfulCallTimeInMillisecs() + "ms;e:" + getAvgFailedCallTimeInMillisecs() + "ms)" + "}";
}
```

The AOP wrap point:

```
public Object wrap(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    JmxStatistics jmxs = store.getStatisticsBean(joinPoint);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object result;
    try {
        result = joinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        long runtime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        jmxs.incrementErrorCount();
        jmxs.increaseErrorCallTime(runtime);
        throw t;
    }
    long runtime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    jmxs.incrementSuccessCount();
    jmxs.increaseSuccessCallTime(runtime);
    return result;
}
```

And a store for exposing all (programatically created) JMX beans:

```
public class JmxStatisticsStore {

private final HashMap<String, JmxStatistics> jmxBeans = new HashMap<>();

public HashMap<String, JmxStatistics> getJmxBeans() {
    return jmxBeans;
}

JmxStatistics getStatisticsBean(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    String id = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().toString() + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    if (!jmxBeans.containsKey(id)) {
        synchronized (jmxBeans) {
            if (!jmxBeans.containsKey(id)) {
                JmxStatistics jmxStatistics = new JmxStatistics(id);
                jmxBeans.put(id, jmxStatistics);
            }
        }
    }
    return jmxBeans.get(id);
}
}
```

I would like to use Spring AOP and MBeanExporter for this. My configuration is the following:

```
<bean id="jmxStatisticsStore" class="package.JmxStatisticsStore"/>
<bean id="jmxAspect" class="package.AspectJJmxCalculator" />
<aop:config>        
    <aop:aspect id="jmxAspectId" ref="jmxAspect">

        <aop:pointcut id="pointCutAround"
                      expression="execution(* jmx.tester..*.*(..))" />

        <aop:around method="wrap" pointcut-ref="pointCutAround"  />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
            <entry key="bean:name=callStatistics" value-ref="jmxStatisticsStore"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Currently, I try to run it in tomcat (the jmx.tester package has a Spring bean that I use in a webapp). The webapp is running correctly, and with JConsole I can connect to the server. On the server, under beans I can see the callStatistics bean, with the HashMap Attribute.

Until I don't make a call, the hashmap is empty (which is good) (on the "Value" box it shows {})
After I make a call (so the hashmap is not empty anymore), the Value becomes Unavailable, and if I try to call the getJmxBeans method through JMX I get the following exception:

```
Problem invoking getJmxBeans: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.JmxStatistics (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

EDIT: What I would like to see is that the calls for the different Ids show as separate JMX attributes.

Is there any way to do what I want to accomplish?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this.
Modified the JmxStatisticsStore:

```
@Autowired
MBeanExporter exporter;

private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();
private final HashMap<String, Object> jmxBeans = new HashMap();

JmxData getStatisticsBean(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    String id = "bean:name=" + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().toString() + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    if (!jmxBeans.containsKey(id)) {
        synchronized (jmxBeans) {
            if (!jmxBeans.containsKey(id)) {
                JmxData jmxStatistics = new JmxData(id);
                jmxBeans.put(id, jmxStatistics);
                try {
                    exporter.registerManagedResource(jmxStatistics, new ObjectName(id));
                } catch (MalformedObjectNameException ex) {
                    LOG.warn("Error while registering " + id, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (JmxData) jmxBeans.get(id);
}
```

This way this creates the new MBeans at runtime

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you [Metrics library](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/).

It has [Spring integration](http://www.ryantenney.com/metrics-spring/) and reports via [JMX](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/getting-started/#reporting-via-jmx).

Use this library into Spring is very easy using annotations. This is an example;

> public class Foo {
>
> ```
> @Timed
> public void bar() { /* … */ }
>
> public void baz() {
>     this.bar(); // doesn't pass through the proxy
>
>     // fix: reengineer
>     // workaround: enable `expose-proxy` and change to:
>     ((Foo) AopContext.currentProxy()).bar(); // hideous, but it works
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Hmmm... will check this later if it is better than our current solution